# Very slow pacman download speed in fresh Manjaro installation

Tags: wireless-networking, arch-linux, manjaro, throttling

After a system error, I had to reinstall my Linux distribution. The wifi was working fine before. After the reinstall, I had to run `sudo pacman -Syu` to get all the packages updated. At first, it was actually working very well. And then the speeds dropped to a beyond-low `15 KiB/s`.

I have tried connecting to the 5G and 2.4G bands, using a VPN, changing QoS settings in my router, and rebooting both the computer and router. I have tried changing my mirror list. I have even tried connecting via ethernet (which was inexplicably even slower). I have tried connecting through the modem built-in router instead of the router I have. The only possible solution I could come up with was my ISP throttling both my VPN *and* Arch Linux mirrors.

Further proof - My TV is streaming crystal-clear at 4K. Going to other websites (ex. Google, superuser) on this computer had no downsides. And two separate internet speed tests have given high results (>50 MB/s).

I would love to have some quick help on this, because my computer kind of depends on this update.

Comment: Add on your post the hardware setup.

Comment: Did you have installed on that machine *only* Linux or there is *one another(? If so, verify whether that issue are *occuring* on that system too.

Comment: @JorgeLuiz The issue was resolved a while ago, actually. The speed was still very slow, but I just waited for a long time and it finally was able to finish the update. It didn't have this problem again.

As for your questions, I do not know my exact wifi card, but my ethernet card is Realtek. Windows was also installed, but I didn't check it.

Comment: [When happening other similar issue you can use the *lpci* command to check out your hardware setup.](https://www.poftut.com/linux-lspci-command-tutorial-with-examples/)

Comment: `04:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8822CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter`

So it was Realtek

Comment: if you has solved fully your issue, so, reply that post with the solution for aggreagating some knonwledge for this community. That would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just using a VPN and downloading the files normally. It took a long time. If you have this problem, a VPN might increase the dowload speed over time.